# require from inside of folder

Tags: php, require, require-once, dirname

Inside my admin folder i have index.php and i can't make it load, i put `require_once dirname(__DIR__).'/includes/header.php';` inside, to load header.php that is inside includes folder, and the same for footer.php. But i get this error:

```
Warning: require_once(functions/sanitize.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\Monk Studio 24.08.2016\core\init.php on line 25

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'functions/sanitize.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\Monk Studio 24.08.2016\core\init.php on line 25
```

Inside header.php i have `require_once dirname(__DIR__).'/core/init.php';` and it works fine. The problem is i think because `/admin/index.php` is including `/includes/header.php` and he is including `/core/init.php` that has includes for `/functions/sanitize.php` and others...

I'm confused...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 1):

> Instead of the require_once try for the include option

Replace:

```
require_once dirname(__DIR__).'/includes/header.php';
```

With

```
include('includes/header.php');
```

Hope so this shall make a trick for you

Comment: Share me if you face hindrance again after implementing the code :)

Comment: In which file are you adding this :)

Comment: In /admin/index.php

Comment: Where is your header.php file located.. Can you post the file structure

Comment: [link](http://image.prntscr.com/image/6c22e48c072945f3a52dd08710d23a71.png)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122072/discussion-between-naresh-kumar-p-and-monk).

Comment: The answer is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory